# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not changing the object location

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

if (interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 260, 200)];

if (interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 400, 200)];

if (interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 400, 200)];


if (interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 260, 200)];

return YES;

 }
```

I am trying to change the size and location of my embedYouTube when rotate, but it is not working .

it is rotating probably , but not changing the location and size .

Answer (score 3):

Try to move your code to the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: method

Comment: If it's not working within the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method, maybe it's your embedYouTube:frame: method's fault

Comment: embedYouTube:frame it is working , but when rotate it is not changing the size  to be suitable for landscape

Comment: is your willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method called ?

Comment: yes just for landscape but when I get back to portrait it not changing

Comment: to have the correct size for portrait I have to go to the previous viewcontroller

Comment: The `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is the correct place to do it (or, even better, in iOS 5 your should use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`). Regarding your failure for this to work, have you checked that `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is getting called? For example, sometimes people try to transition to a new view by creating a `controller` and then doing `[self.view addSubview:controller.view]` which is a bad idea because it prevents rotation events from ever getting to the new view controller. Regardless, just confirm that your rotation callbacks are called.

Answer (score 2):

At your viewDidLoad method, add an observer for listening UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                      name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

You should use UIDevice's beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications to start getting notifications.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

at didRotate method, get current orientation, and set frame accordingly.

didRotate method is like below.

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification { 
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 260, 200)];

if (orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 400, 200)];

if (orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 400, 200)];

if (orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    [self embedYouTube:yout frame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 260, 200)]; 
}
```

And dont forget to remove observer at dealloc method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: do I have to create the didRotate method or it is built in ?

Comment: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification will not be called unless you start generating by calling a method in UIDevice, but that's not the way!

Comment: please I am getting error and crash the app , can you help me with didRotate please ?

Comment: @EPyLEpSY it is work well but when I get back to the portrait mood it is stay as landscape and not changing the size and location .

Comment: it should actually. Try to NSLog at your embedYouTube method, what size and location values are coming.